# How to send new user invite to set up password in devise (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable, devise-invitable

I have a users model I call admin.

Instead of me setting up their password, I would like to create the admin and have system send user an email which has them set up their password.

I’m just a little confused on how to do this. Should I use devise confirmable, or perhaps devise_inevitable gem?

I’d really appreciate any insight here from people with experience in setting this up.

Comment: Devise invitable is for inviting people to the app, so if the admin is inviting everyone to the app that is a good choice, but not if people are signing up, then confirmable is the way to go.  It will send an email when they put in their email address and when they follow the link they set their password.

Comment: You could also generate a password and send it to them in the email. Not as secure as they sign up and confirm, but then an admin user can create an account for them. `generated_password = Devise.friendly_token.first(x)` where x is the number of characters in the password.